# Difference between "intercept" and "intersect"

Tags: soft-question, terminology

What is the difference between *intercept* and *intersect*? Can they be used interchangeably? For example, intersecting lines and intercepting lines.

Comment: *Intercept* seems more appropriate as a noun (e.g. "Find the x-intercepts of f(x)"). *Intersect* seems more appropriate as a verb (e.g. "Find where f interests the x-axis")

Comment: *Intercepting* has no meaning.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 not to be confused with "interests" (which you wrote instead of intersects).

Answer (score 8):

There is a temporal element to *intercept* which is absent from *intersect*: if two paths are generated respectively by two particles moving through space, the paths may intersect; however, one particle only intercepts the other if they arrive at the point of intersection simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

The words "intercept" and "intersect" sound very similar but mean different things.

"Intersect" is a binary (two-valued) qualitative property of two or more sets and means that they have points in common, e.g., curves cross or areas overlap etc. Those points in common are called their "intersection." So, for example, every pair of sides of a triangle "intersect" at a point called the vertex of the triangle. In fact the word "vertex" REFERS to the point where two sides of a triangle meet. So as The Chaz commented, "intersect" is a verb.

On the other hand, an "intercept" is a quantitative property of of a curve. It refers to a specific point where the curve INTERSECTS one of the axes of the coordinate system, the particular axis lending its name to identify the intercept, such as "x intercept," etc. So an "intercept" is a particular intersection, usually referring to that point of a curve that is in common (crosses or first touches) another curve, usually a coordinate system axis.

Answer (score 1):

An intersection point is a  meeting point of two straight or curved transversal lines.

A length of line included between two points of intersection is a line segment or intercept.

A single line is a segment between its endpoints but is not an intercept.

Answer (score -1):

Technically intersection is  defined as, it is a meeting point of two variabled curve which varied  as  time ie, the  equations of curves will vary.
        But in case of intercept, one  curve  equation is  constant  and  other is  varied  as its bounded  area.

Comment: I have edited your post to correct grammar at least in places, where I know what words you wanted to use. But I have to admit that I do not understand what you are trying to say.